# give divs class name inside table td

Tags: javascript, class, html, appendchild

I'm trying to give a bunch of divs the same class name inside of another div, and by doing that, I hope to put each child div into a td inside a table.

I can't change the html/css sheets.

Hope you can help!

http://jsfiddle.net/6mkYL/1/

html:

```
<div id="puzzlearea">
            <!-- the following are the fifteen puzzle pieces -->
            <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
function loading () {
    function nameBox () {
        var bigBox = document.getElementById("puzzlearea");
        var divs = bigBox.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].className = "boxes";
        }
    }
    function tableCreate () {
        var body = document.getElementById('puzzlearea');
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        tbl.style.width = '400px';
        tbl.style.height = '400px';
        tbl.cellPadding = '0';
        tbl.cellSpacing = '0';
        tbl.setAttribute('border', '2');
        var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i == 3 && j == 4) {break} else {
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.appendChild("boxes");
                    tr.appendChild(td)
                }
            }
            tbdy.appendChild(tr);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
        body.appendChild(tbl)
    }
    tableCreate();
};
window.onload = function () {
    loading();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, you had a bunch of syntax errors and some missteps in logic, but I've kept the overall format of the program the same:

```
function loading () {
    function nameBox () {
        var bigBox = document.getElementById("puzzlearea");
        var divs = bigBox.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].className = "boxes";
        }

        // Notice I return the node list of divs so you can use it to populate
        // your grid in tableCreate
        return divs;
    }
    function tableCreate () {
        var body = document.getElementById('puzzlearea'),
            tbl  = document.createElement('table'),
            boxes = nameBox();

        // I would recommend removing this block and simply setting these
        // style attributes in CSS under an id that you give to your table
        tbl.style.width = '400px';
        tbl.style.height = '400px';
        tbl.cellPadding = '0';
        tbl.cellSpacing = '0';
        tbl.setAttribute('border', '2');

        var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            // Notice how I've added boxes.length as a loop condition
            // this will automatically break the loop once the boxes
            // node list is empty
            for (var j = 0; j < 4 && boxes.length; j++) {
                    var td = document.createElement('td');

                    // You were appending the string "boxes" here
                    // I've changed it to append the first div
                    // remaining in the boxes node list
                    td.appendChild([].shift.call(boxes););
                    tr.appendChild(td)
            }
            tbdy.appendChild(tr);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
        body.appendChild(tbl)
    }
    tableCreate();
};
window.onload = function () {
    loading();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about this but maybe you should try putting your puzzle-area and div to be global variables..ie..

```
function loading()
{
var bigBox = document.getElementById('puzzlearea'),
```

`       divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), i;

```
function nameBox()
{
for( i=0; i<divs.length; i++ )
{
divs[i].className = 'boxes';
}
}
}
```

and then go on with the other function just modifying the variable..

Comment: I'm not sure either, but there's this odd line in `tableCreate()`: `td.appendChild("boxes");`. Maybe you can figure out, what OP wants to do here? As it is, it surely causes an error.

Comment: **NOOO!** Never encourage the use of global variables in JS, they are the cause of much terrible woe. It is known.

Comment: the variable is bug global in the loading function scope and not the entire window so it should work, besides, he's having to redeclare two different variables that refer to the same 'div-id', it could be part of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were tryin to acheive this :-

```
function loading() {
        function nameBox() {
            var bigBox = document.getElementById("puzzlearea");
            var divs = bigBox.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
                divs[i].style.cssFloat = "left";
                divs[i].style.width = "19%";
                divs[i].style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
                divs[i].style.textAlign="center";
            }
        }
        nameBox();
    }
loading();
```

It is JSFIDDLED [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gurunave/6mkYL/10/)